# An example of a maximal consistent set?

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

I an doing old exams, and there is an exercise that asks to give an example of a maximal consistent set, and while i understand the definition, I cant seem to find or come up with an example.

Answer (score 1):

Pick some assignment of truth values to your propositional variables (for example, decide that they're all true). Then take the set of all formulas which are true under this valuation. It is a consequence of the completeness theorem for propositional logic that every maximal consistent set has this form.